# Changing email format with javascript

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, activex, email-formats

I am sending emails via an html page using javascript and the outlook activex object (Outlook.Application) I am trying to change the format of the mail message to html but I don't know to what value I must set the .BodyFormat property. I've tried this:

```
objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML;
```

but olFormatHTML is undefined; Can I only use this constant with VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HTMLBody` property like this:

```
objMail.HTMLBody = "YOUR HTML CODE HERE";
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1003014&page=1